# How to use Python to extract Date Info (Month day, year) from a string column in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, date-formatting, date-conversion

I am now doing a Python programming task on a data set of movie industry, from the Kaggle website dataset https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/danielgrijalvas/movies .

I imported the dataset into a Pandas dataframe **df**.  There is a column **"released"**, of type "str", i.e. string, with character string date data format as the followings:

```
>>> df.released[:10]
```

| index | Date Strings look like below |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | June 13, 1980 (United States) |
| 1 | July 2, 1980 (United States) |
| 2 | June 20, 1980 (United States) |
| 3 | July 2, 1980 (United States) |
| 4 | July 25, 1980 (United States) |
| 5 | May 9, 1980 (United States) |
| 6 | June 20, 1980 (United States) |
| 7 | December 19, 1980 (United States) |
| 8 | June 19, 1981 (United States) |
| 9 | May 16, 1980 (United States) |

*Name: released, dtype: objects*

```
>>> type(df.released[0])
```

*str*

I would like to extract/convert the date information inside this **"released"** column of such character string format, discarding the country name with the brackets, into another new dataframe column, of data type either as the **pandas.Timestamp** format, or the Python **datetime** format.

I searched the Internet a lot and cannot find a good solution of Python codes/functions to do such extraction/conversion.

Could anyone help?

Best Regards
Alex Chu

Answer (score 0):

You will want to split on the `(` so that the date and the country are separated, then call `to_datetime` on the dates.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['released'].str.split(' \(').str[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pd.to_datetime() after splitting the column accordingly should work. Kindly try:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['released'].str.split(r'(')).str[0],infer_datetime_format=True)
```

As an example:

```
pd.to_datetime('June 13, 1980',infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Returns:

```
Timestamp('1980-06-13 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to your answers.

Last night I managed to reference Python codes from others, and write some codes to do it successfully:

```
# create a function to discard the "(country)" part of the string

def get_date(date):
    if '(' in date:
        date = date[:date.index('(')]
    return date[:-1].strip()

# extract the date-only-part of the string from the dataframe column "released"

df['rel_date'] = df.released.apply(lambda date: get_date(str(date)))
df['rel_date'].head()

# convert the date string, into another column of "datetime" data type

df["date_added"] = pd.to_datetime(df['rel_date'])
df['year_added'] = df['date_added'].dt.year
df['month_added'] = df['date_added'].dt.month

df["date_added"].head()

# convert the "datetime" type column, into a new column of data type as Pandas "Timestamp"

df["rel_timestamp"] = df['date_added'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x))
df["rel_timestamp"].head()
```

It seems the following two methods generate the same result:

```
df["new_column"] = pd.to_datetime(df['rel_date'])

df["new_column"] = df["rel_date"].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
```

I wonder, when to use the first one: passing the dataframe column as argument to the "pd.to_datetime" method;  and when to use the second one: use ".apply" and use a "lambda" function.

Best Regards

Alex Chu